# Using Python trie to build transactionsTrie. Why is my Transactionsroot wrong?

Tags: transactions, python, merkle-patricia-tries

I am trying to build a TransactionsTrie with python. I am using this [trie][1]-Library. I followed the Instructions.

Edit: Removed the original question because it was stupid.

@carver 
Thank you very much. Your reply was really helpful. So I am trying to use the method You referenced from py-evm.

Here is my full code:

```
import requests
import json
import ethereum.utils as utils
from eth.db.trie import make_trie_root_and_nodes as make_trie
from eth.rlp.transactions import BaseTransactionFields
from eth.rlp.transactions import BaseTransaction

url = 'https://ropsten.infura.io/1234'

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
data = {}
data['jsonrpc'] = '2.0'
data['id'] = 1
data['method'] = 'eth_getBlockByHash'
data['params'] = ["0xd993562b847a2b61f858ee2baa2351f05e22d755d3657444f06a8c51f88a11f8", True]
data = json.dumps(data)

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=str(data) )
print(response.text)
block = json.loads(response.text)
result = block['result']
raw_transactions = result['transactions']

transactions = tuple()
for tx in raw_transactions:
    nonce = tx['nonce']
    nonce = utils.int_to_big_endian(int(nonce[2:], 16))
    gas_price = tx['gasPrice']
    gas_price = utils.int_to_big_endian(int(gas_price[2:], 16))
    gas = tx['gas']
    gas = utils.int_to_big_endian(int(gas[2:], 16))
    to = tx['to']
    to = bin(int(to[2:], 16))
    value = tx['value']
    value = utils.int_to_big_endian(int(value[2:], 16))
    data = tx['input']
    print(data)
    if data != '0x':
        data = bin(int(data[2:], 16))
    else:
        data = bin(0)
    print(data)
    v = tx['v']
    v = utils.int_to_big_endian(int(v[2:], 16))
    r = tx['r']
    r = utils.int_to_big_endian(int(r[2:], 16))
    s = tx['s']
    s = utils.int_to_big_endian(int(s[2:], 16))
    f = BaseTransactionFields(nonce = nonce, gas_price = gas_price, gas = gas, to = to, value = value, data = data, v = v, r = r, s = s)
    transactions += tuple(f)

tx_root, _ = make_trie(transactions)
print(tx_root.hex())
```

Still my txRoot is not the same as the one in the Block. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't use `BaseTransactionFields` directly, for one. It's hard to say without looking at one specific transaction that is not encoding correctly. Are all transactions failing, or just some? Try to narrow it down to a single transaction that's not encoding correctly by doing `Web3.sha3(rlp.encode(rebuilt_transaction)) == original_tx['hash']`. Then a newly posted question could be focused on something like "why is my hash of this specific transaction not matching the client's hash?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building a transaction trie in Ethereum, both key and value are rlp-encoded. The key is the zero-based order of inclusion, and the value is the full transaction (not the hash).

You can see an example utility that [trinity uses to generate the transaction trie](https://github.com/ethereum/py-evm/blob/2d4594a19f6188938281db2f4c122201c0a21d3f/eth/db/trie.py#L22) (edited for clarity):

```
items = tuple(rlp.encode(object) for object in rlp_objects)

kv_store = {}  # type: Dict[Hash32, bytes]
trie = HexaryTrie(kv_store, BLANK_ROOT_HASH)

for index, item in enumerate(items):
    index_key = rlp.encode(index, sedes=rlp.sedes.big_endian_int)
    trie[index_key] = item

transaction_root = trie.root_hash
```

Comment: could you be so kind to take some of your very valuable time to tell me why I'm Stupid? See the Edit.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record I am posting my complete code, so that maybe someone else can use it :)

```
def _create_transaction(*, nonce, gasprice, startgas, to, value, data=b'', v=None, r=None, s=None, network_id=None):
    if to:
        to = address_decoder(to)
    else:
        to = b''

    if network_id is not None:
        if r is not None or s is not None:
            raise Exception(
                "cannot set network id at the same time as r and s values")
        v = network_id

    tx = Transaction(nonce, gasprice, startgas, to,
                     value, data, v or 0, r or 0, s or 0)
    tx._sender = None

    return tx


def create_transaction(tx):

    nonce = tx['nonce']
    gas_price = tx['gasPrice']
    gas = tx['gas']
    to = tx['to']
    value = tx['value']
    data = tx['input'][2:]
    if data == "":
        data = b''
    else:
        data = data_decoder(data)
    v = tx['v']
    r = int.from_bytes(tx['r'], byteorder='big')
    s = int.from_bytes(tx['s'], byteorder='big')
    return _create_transaction(nonce=nonce, gasprice=gas_price, startgas=gas, to=to, data=data, value=value, v=v, r=r, s=s)


def make_trie_root_and_nodes(items: Transactions) -> TrieRootAndData:
    return _make_trie_root_and_nodes(tuple(rlp.encode(item) for item in items))


def _make_trie_root_and_nodes(items: Tuple[bytes, ...]) -> TrieRootAndData:
    kv_store = {}  # type: Dict[Hash32, bytes]
    trie = HexaryTrie(kv_store)
    with trie.squash_changes() as memory_trie:
        for index, item in enumerate(items):
            index_key = rlp.encode(index, sedes=rlp.sedes.big_endian_int)
            memory_trie[index_key] = item
    return trie.root_hash, kv_store
```

the make_trie_root_and_nodes functions are copied(and slightly modified) from [here (trinity)](https://github.com/ethereum/py-evm/blob/2d4594a19f6188938281db2f4c122201c0a21d3f/eth/db/trie.py#L22)